# Why Nullable<int> doesn't have any members?

Tags: c#, int

Why does the following line work:

```
int.Parse("SomeIntegerValue");
```

but the following doesn't:

```
int?.Parse("SomeIntegerValue");
```

For a second i thought the parser was not able to parse `int?` as a type, so I changed it to:

```
(int?).Parse("SomeIntegerValue");
```

but that doesn't work either. Neither does the more verbose form:

```
Nullable<int>.Parse("SomeIntegerValue");
```

or

```
(Nullable<int>).Parse("SomeIntegerValue");
```

This last version tells me that `Nullable<int>` is a type but used like a variable, but then even the simple `int` is a type, right?

Comment: Show me the `Parse` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Put a string which may contain an int into an int, but allow `"null"` or maybe an empty string? As for your last point, trying `int.ToString()` won't work cos you've used a type like a variable, right?

Comment: @doctorlove: Correct. I was expecting `int?` to be able to `Parse` everything that an `int` can `Parse`, plus empty strings. I just forgot the fact that `int?` doesn't derive from `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) is a generic structure, where `T` can be any ValueType, user defined or otherwise.

It would make no sense for it to have a `Parse()` method that is only applicable for about a dozen built-in datatypes and useless for everything else.

Comment: grrrr... why didn't I think of that *simple* thing. `Nullable<Thanks>` to you.

Comment: *Theoretically*, it could use [`TypeDescriptor.GetConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewtxwhzx(v=vs.110).aspx) under the hood, but that would seem like an unnecessary dirty hack. There is no benefit in having this over simply using a highly performant static method.

Comment: Your point is reasonable, but not always true. For example, [`Activator.CreateInstance<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx) does not place any restrictions on the type `T` in its signature, but the implementation will throw a `MissingMethodException` if you try to use it with a type that does not have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @280Z28 To some extent I agree, however the _purpose_ of `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` is to invoke a constructor and there isn't really a way around having it fail for certain inputs. The purpose of `Nullable<T>` has nothing to do with parsing, so it would make no sense for it to have a `Parse()` method that is only applicable to a very small set of datatypes. However, I have reworded my answer to express my intent a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because `Nullable<T>` does not have `Parse()` method.